# php $_POST output error

Tags: php, html

I am trying simple web form action in PHP, whatever input given to in the input field output value is `1`. and undefined index error for `username`, `password` when `isset` not present before the `$_POST`

```
<html>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit"></form>
</html>

<?php
$usernmae=isset($_POST["username"]);
$pass=isset($_POST["password"]);
echo $usernmae," ",$pass;
?>
```

Comment: remove isset function

Comment: Quick tip: `<form action="" method="post">` will post back to the current URL, which is useful if you decide to do "pretty URLs" later on. It also preserves all query string parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
    /*** if else in a single statement ****/
    $username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
    $pass     = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : "";
    echo $username." - ".$pass;
?>
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but you should provide some explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Dont use

```
$usernmae=isset($_POST["username"]);
$pass=isset($_POST["password"]);
```

Put only

```
$usernmae=$_POST["username"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];
```

Because **isset()** gives boolean values i.e. 1 or 0. In your case **isset($_POST["username"])** checks that you have put values in this field or not. if there is some values in username field then it return 1 otherwise returns 0.

Comment: improve your answer by elaborating why :)

Comment: `isset()` does not "give 1 or 0". It returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
$usernmae= $_POST["username"];
$pass= $_POST["password"];
echo $usernmae," ",$pass;
```

`isset($_POST["username"])` and `isset($_POST["password"])` return `1` if evaluation is `TRUE` since `isset()` return boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Others have told you ***how*** to solve the problem. I will tell you ***what*** the problem is.

### Problems

You need to know following things:

#### PHP's boolean to string implicit conversion

When implicitly converting a boolean to a string, [PHP acts a bit weird](http://www.f15ijp.com/2010/07/php-converting-a-bool-value-to-a-string-value/).

```
$testVar = false;
echo (string)$testVar; //will output a empty string (as that evaluates to false)
$testVar = true;
echo (string)$testVar; //will output 1 (as that evaluates to true)
```

#### How `isset()` works

According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php),

> Returns `TRUE` if [variable supplied as argument] exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.

#### What happens when you try to access a $_POST parameter

As you very well know, `$_POST` parameters are available to a PHP script when,

1. There is an HTML form, of which `action` attribute points to the PHP script
2. User submits the form, with or without data

If the `name` attribute of a field in the form was `"username"`, you can access this information from the PHP script after the submission of the form like this:

```
$_POST["username"]
```

But if the PHP script that processes the `$_POST` parameters are in the same file as the HTML form, no `$_POST` parameters will be available to the script when it is initially accessed.

And if you tried to access `$_POST` parameters when there are none, the result is `Undefined index`.

### What's happening here?

With the understanding of the above three things, we can deduce what's happening in your case.

When your file is loaded on the first time to the browser, PHP interpreter has to interpret it first. But on this first time, no `$_POST` variables are present. So when you try to access `$_POST` parameters, it will result in an `Undefined index` error.

When you wrap the `$_POST["..."]` expressions in an `isset()`, `isset()` will return `FALSE`, because the parameters are simply not there. Since `FALSE` is converted to empty string (`""`), your `echo` statement produces nothing visible.

When you submit the form, the `isset()` calls will return `TRUE`, because the `$_POST` parameters are present this time. And as described above, `TRUE` becomes `"1"` when converted to strings. Hence you get the output `1`.

## Solution

You must always check before you access `$_POST` parameters.

```
$username = "";
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
}
```

Or shorthand:

```
$username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using `isset($_POST["username"])`? The `isset()` function return false if testing variable contains a NULL value and true otherwise.

Try like

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
   $usernmae=$_POST["username"];
   $pass=$_POST["password"];
   echo $usernmae," ",$pass;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if a value exists first. If you don't, you will get an error.
thus `isset($_POST['VALUE'])`
If it exists, get it. If not, set to "empty"

```
<html>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit"></form>
</html>
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Devunne3
 * Date: 25/09/14
 * Time: 12:32
 */
$usernmae=isset($_POST["username"])?$_POST['username']:'';
$pass=isset($_POST["password"])?$_POST['password']:'';
echo $usernmae," ",$pass;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line

```
$usernmae=isset($_POST["username"]);
$pass=isset($_POST["password"]);
```

You're saving the value of `isset()`, which is a boolean 0 or 1.

Since the 2 params are set you're getting the 1 (true).

You want to do this:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
    $usernmae = $_POST['username'];
}
```

and the same for the password.

Answer (score 2):

try this. and the reason you you are getting 1 and 1, because you are using

```
$usernmae=isset($_POST["username"]);
```

That is one couase you set it.

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){
   $usernmae=$_POST["username"];
   $pass=$_POST["password"];
   echo $usernmae," ",$pass;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the bottom 3 lines with

```
$username=isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';
$pass=isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:'';
echo $username," ",$pass
```

The isset() returns boolean, whether the variable is set or not. That makes it return 1. In my answer if the field has value, it will echo the value if not, will echo blank string

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
 {
  $usernmae=$_POST["username"];
  $pass=$_POST["password"];
  echo "User Name is : ".$usernmae,"Password is : ".$pass;
 }
```